# java.lang.StackOverflowError with Spark 2.0.2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am using Spark 2.0.2 and GraphX 2.0.2 in a Scala project. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.5. 
I have this error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError 
        at org.apache.spark.io.LZ4BlockInputStream.read(LZ4BlockInputStream.java:125) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2606) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2622)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:3123) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHandle(ObjectInputStream.java:1646) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1707) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1986) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013) 
        ...
```

Comment: maybe you have a divergent recursion ?

Comment: @DaliMidou can you add your code, so that we can see what causes this problem?

Comment: Please add more details, like what you were trying to do and what exactly didn't work. This stack trace is not particularly helpful apart from something about decompression while reading some data (probably).

Comment: Any update on this ?